# Access 2013 - Visual Basic issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am experiencing an issue with Access 2013 while creating some VBA code with a button. I would like my button to open an form using: DoCmd.OpenForm
With this command i would like to implement an WHILE condition which filters the form which is going to be opened.

I have 2 fields on the current form with:
- Start Date
- End Data

The WHILE condition must filter all records Where the column "Date" is between the 2 given dates in the previous form. So actually i would like to do something like this:

```
WHERE date >= Me.begin_date.value AND date <= Me.eind_date.value
```

I cant simply figure it out to use it in the WHILE condition of the VBA code. I can however do other things with filters in VBA like:

```
search_filter = "ItemID LIKE '*" & Me.search_bar.Value & "*' "
DoCmd.OpenForm "#3 search-result", acNormal, , search_filter
```

But now i want to have the first code sample, translated to the VBA code just like the above piece of code.

How can i achieve this?

Sorry for my bad English btw.

Answer (score 0):

if i recall correctly;

generate a query based on those two values (in the query builer will do) then
forms!formname.recordsource = sql for that query here

Comment: But if i create a query that is standalone from the original form, i cant recall on those values that are on that form. So the query wont even work.

Comment: er, you can, you write the query that is linked to the values in the fields of the forms but looks like you have it sorted gladly :)

Answer (score 0):

My Question was answered on another forum (tweakers.net).

```
search_filter = "Date BETWEEN #" & Me.begin_date.Value & "# AND #" & Me.end_date.Value & "#"
```

It did the trick.